# Why updateNodeList Failed when installing oracle grid infrastructure 12c RAC?

Tags: oracle, rac

When installing Oracle 12c grid infrastructure I received error and must run the following command :
`/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin/runInstaller -updateNodeList -setCustomNodelist -noClusterEnabled ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/12.1.0/grid CLUSTER_NODES=kaash-his-1,kaash-his-2 "NODES_TO_SET={kaash-his-1,kaash-his-2}" CRS=false "INVENTORY_LOCATION=/u01/app/oraInventory" LOCAL_NODE=kaash-his-2`

When I run the command the result failed .

```
    -bash-4.2$ /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin/runInstaller -updateNodeList -setCustomNodelist -noClusterEnabled ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/12.1.0/grid CLUSTER_NODES=kaash-his-1,kaash-his-2 "NODES_TO_SET={kaash-his-1,kaash-his-2}" CRS=false "INVENTORY_LOCATION=/u01/app/oraInventory" LOCAL_NODE=kaash-his-2ACLE_HOME=/u01/app/12.1.0/grid CLUSTER_NODES=kaash-his-1,kaash-his-2 "NODES_TStarting Oracle Universal Installer...
    
    Checking swap space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 28607 MB    Passed
    Exception oracle.sysman.oii.oiil.OiilNativeException: S_OWNER_SYSTEM_EPERM occurred..
    oracle.sysman.oii.oiil.OiilNativeException: S_OWNER_SYSTEM_EPERM
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.unix.OiipuUnixOps.chgrp(Native Method)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgBootstrap.changeGroup(OiipgBootstrap.java:1468)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgBootstrap.writeInvLoc(OiipgBootstrap.java:1113)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgBootstrap.updateInventoryLoc(OiipgBootstrap.java:463)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiii.OiiiInstallAreaControl.createInventory(OiiiInstallAreaControl.java:5394)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiii.OiiiInstallAreaControl.initAreaControlWithAccessCheck(OiiiInstallAreaControl.java:1826)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initAreaControl(OiicStandardInventorySession.java:316)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicStandardInventorySession.java:276)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicStandardInventorySession.java:238)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicStandardInventorySession.java:187)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.getInstallAreaControl(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:993)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicBaseInventoryApp.main_helper(OiicBaseInventoryApp.java:756)
    at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicUpdateNodeList.main(OiicUpdateNodeList.java:492)
    'UpdateNodeList' failed.
    'UpdateNodeList' failed.
```

This is the log file :

```
[grid@KAASH-HIS-2 logs]$ cat UpdateNodeList2023-02-12_12-11-10AM.log
The file oraparam.ini could not be found at /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin/oraparam.ini
Using paramFile: /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/oraparam.ini


Checking swap space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 28607 MB    Passed

Execvp of the child jre : the cmdline is ../../jdk/jre/bin/java, and the argv is 
../../jdk/jre/bin/java
-Doracle.installer.library_loc=../lib/linux64
-Doracle.installer.oui_loc=/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin/..
-Doracle.installer.bootstrap=FALSE
-Doracle.installer.startup_location=/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin
-Doracle.installer.jre_loc=../../jdk/jre
-Doracle.installer.custom_inventory=/u01/app/oraInventory
-Doracle.installer.nlsEnabled="TRUE"
-Doracle.installer.prereqConfigLoc= 
-Doracle.installer.unixVersion=5.4.17-2136.315.5.el7uek.x86_64
-Xms150m
-Xmx256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M
-cp
/tmp/OraInstall2023-02-12_12-11-10AM::/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/wsclient_extended.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/emCoreConsole.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/jsch.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/remoteinterfaces.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/OraPrereq.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/orai18n-utility.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/OraPrereqChecks.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/adf-share-ca.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/jmxspi.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/instcommon.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/installcommons_1.0.0b.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/ojdbc6.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/instcrs.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/cvu.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/entityManager_proxy.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/javax.security.jacc_1.0.0.0_1-1.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/prov_fixup.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/orai18n-mapping.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/emca.jar:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin//../../inventory/Scripts/ext/jlib/ssh.jar:../jlib/OraInstaller.jar:../jlib/oneclick.jar:../jlib/xmlparserv2.jar:../jlib/share.jar:../jlib/OraInstallerNet.jar:../jlib/emCfg.jar:../jlib/emocmutl.jar:../jlib/OraPrereq.jar:../jlib/jsch.jar:../jlib/ssh.jar:../jlib/remoteinterfaces.jar:../jlib/http_client.jar:../jlib/OraSuiteInstaller.jar:../jlib/opatch.jar:../jlib/opatchactions.jar:../jlib/opatchprereq.jar:../jlib/opatchutil.jar:../jlib/OraCheckPoint.jar:../jlib/InstImages.jar:../jlib/InstHelp.jar:../jlib/InstHelp_de.jar:../jlib/InstHelp_es.jar:../jlib/InstHelp_fr.jar:../jlib/InstHelp_it.jar:../jlib/InstHelp_ja.jar:../jlib/InstHelp_ko.jar:../jlib/InstHelp_pt_BR.jar:../jlib/InstHelp_zh_CN.jar:../jlib/InstHelp_zh_TW.jar:../jlib/oracle_ice.jar:../jlib/help-share.jar:../jlib/ohj.jar:../jlib/ewt3.jar:../jlib/ewt3-swingaccess.jar:../jlib/swingaccess.jar::../jlib/jewt4.jar:../jlib/orai18n-collation.jar:../jlib/orai18n-mapping.jar:../jlib/ojmisc.jar:../jlib/xml.jar:../jlib/srvm.jar:../jlib/srvmasm.jar
oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicUpdateNodeList
-scratchPath
/tmp/OraInstall2023-02-12_12-11-10AM
-sourceType
network
-timestamp
2023-02-12_12-11-10AM
-updateNodeList
-setCustomNodelist
-noClusterEnabled
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/12.1.0/grid
CLUSTER_NODES=kaash-his-1,kaash-his-2
NODES_TO_SET={kaash-his-1,kaash-his-2}
CRS=false
INVENTORY_LOCATION=/u01/app/oraInventory
LOCAL_NODE=kaash-his-2
```

This is  command on node 2 for grid user :

```
[root@KAASH-HIS-2 ~]# id grid
uid=54323(grid) gid=1002(oinstall) groups=1002(oinstall),1004(dba),1000(asmadmin),1001(asmdba)
```

This is command on node 1 for user grid

```
[grid@KAASH-HIS-1 ~]$ id
uid=54323(grid) gid=1002(oinstall) groups=1002(oinstall),1000(asmadmin),1001(asmdba),1004(dba) context=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0
```

this is the command I need to run before continue the setup

```
/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/bin/runInstaller -jreLoc /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/jdk/jre -paramFile /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oui/clusterparam.ini -silent 
-ignoreSysPrereqs -updateNodeList -bigCluster  ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/12.1.0/grid CLUSTER_NODES=kaash-his-2 "NODES_TO_SET={kaash-his-1,kaash-his-2}"                                        
-invPtrLoc "/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oraInst.loc" -local
```

when I execute the command I got this error

```
The operation failed as it was called without path of Oracle Home being attached
```

how can I attach oracle home and execute the command please ?